# How do you track known users in Sitecore 9 Update 1?

Tags: xdb, xconnect, tracking

I am working on creating an intranet, and I know the users logging in to access the site. I am trying to create and update contacts' personal information. However, I am running into issues with Read-Only attributes.

In Sitecore 8, you could add code to access the contact personal information in session in the Create Visit pipeline. However, in Sitecore 9, this contact personal information is now Read-Only.

I have looked at the Sitecore 9 Web Tracking documentation found here (https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-contacts/identification/index.html) and it uses the xConnect Client API.

Is using the xConnect Client API the only way to update facets on the contacts in Sitecore 9?

Answer (score 2):

YES, updating facets is possible just using xConnect.

[image]

For more details have a look here: https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-contacts/contact-facets/update-facets.html

Comment: If you use the xConnect client to do the updates, how does Sitecore know about the contact? So I set the contact to "known" and update some facets, how does my visit/interaction data get connected with the contact that was created by xConnect?

Comment: @sestocker have a look here: https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-overview/index.html